# How to insert an element into an existing document using XMLBeam?

Tags: java, xml

I need to insert a new element into an existing document using **XMLBeam**.  I can create documents from scratch and read existing docs ok but struggling with the insert.  **How do I insert a new element, as indicated by the comment below in the sample XML, with the id of 3 for example?**

Say I have this XML:

```xml
<p:PEOPLE xmlns:p="people-namespace">
    <p:PERSON id="1">
        <p:FIRST_NAME>John</p:FIRST_NAME>
        <p:LAST_NAME>Smith</p:LAST_NAME>
    </p:PERSON>
    <p:PERSON id="2">
        <p:FIRST_NAME>Sally</p:FIRST_NAME>
        <p:LAST_NAME>Green</p:LAST_NAME>
    </p:PERSON>
    <!-- How to add a new PERSON here with id = 3 ?? -->
</p:PEOPLE>
```

and these projection interfaces:

```java
interface PeopleData {

    @XBRead("/p:PEOPLE")
    List<Person> getAllPeople();

}


interface Person {

    @XBRead("@id")
    int getPersonId();

    @XBRead("p:FIRST_NAME")
    String getFirstName();

    @XBRead("p:LAST_NAME")
    String getLastName();
}
```

I'm reading the data ok as follows:

```java
new XBProjector().io().file("some file name").read(PersonData.class);
```

I'm using Saxon as the XPath engine and have set the namespace context in the factory config as follows:

```java
@Override
public XPath createXPath(Document... document) {
    XPathFactory factory = new XPathFactoryImpl();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new PeopleNamespaceContext());
    return xpath;
}
```

I've tried a few different ways but keep hitting this exception:

```java
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the **DefaultXMLFactoriesConfig.getUserDefinedNamespaceMapping** method

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getUserDefinedNamespaceMapping() {
    return Collections.singletonMap("p", "people-namespace");
}
```

Projection

```
interface PeopleData {

    @XBRead("/p:PEOPLE/p:PERSON")
    List<Person> getAllPeople();

    @XBWrite("/p:PEOPLE/p:PERSON[@id='{0}']")
    PeopleData setPerson(int id, @XBValue Person p);
}
```